Lamp hanging on gypsum acoustic panel
I am thinking of adding a Philips Ensis to my dinner room, but the ceiling has acoustic panels on it. I am not sure what the material is, but I think it is gypsum.
Can it be done? I would really like for it to go over the part with a grid. Then I think I will need some cable to run it to the power marked red?


Gypsum board mostly behaves like plasterboard...

3.5 kg (~8 pounds) plus the weight of a junction box hanging on a suspended ceiling doesn't seem like a good idea. That's not to say that you can't anchor into whatever is above the drop ceiling.
As noted, you'll need to supply power, and it almost certainly isn't coming from the smoke alarm. Strongly suggest you engage the services of a licensed professional.

You can not use that cable.
It is not a power cable.
It is a signal cable for the smoke alarm.
